# how to pass in extra argument in web API call?

Tags: c#-4.0, asp.net-web-api

I am a bit of a web API noob and trying this sample:http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Contact-Manager-Web-API-0e8e373d

What I would like is to pass in an extra argument called 'extraArgument' in the API controller GET-method. The extraArgument parameter is then used as an input to a repository or something.

```
public Contact Get(int id,string extraArgument)
{
    var contact = this.repository.Get(id);
    if (contact == null)
    {
        throw new HttpResponseException(new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotFound));
    }

    return contact;
}
```

Do I need to change the WebApiConfig.Register method? what is needed?

Comment: Just like you have it is fine. What is it that you think won't work?

Comment: Your code looks good and working as it is.

Comment: how do I call it then ? http://localhost:8081/api/contacts/1&extraArgument=hsjfsjdhf?

Comment: Yes, that should do it.